# Not able to connect from excel(2003) to oracle server

Tags: oracle, excel, vba

I am trying to connect to oracle server from excel...i dont want to install oracle client in my system(presently there is no oracle client) So i am using Microsoft ODBC for Oracle

```
 Dim strConnection, conn, rs, strSQL
 strConnection = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=ServerName;Uid=username;Pwd=password;" 
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open strConnection
'insq = "insert into State (States) values ('" + Sheet1.Cells(1, 5) + "')"
'conn.Execute insq
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

The Error is : Oracle Client and networking component not found

I have also tried using connection string

```
trConnection = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=Datasource;User  Id=username;Password=password;"
'strConnection = "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source==Datasource;User Id=username;Password=password;"
```

But still i am getting an error

**My main question is can we connect from excel to oracle server without oracle client
   in my system..**

Comment: As far as I'm aware you don't need it if you have an ODBC driver. If you're worried about disk space, have you considered the Instant Client?

Comment: as per my knowledge odbc driver comes with mdac which already comes
with the OS(i have windows XP SP3)..so i am confused..do we need
any other thing to work my code

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you need something on your system that 'speaks Oracle'. To begin with it needs to  know how the protocol works to get the specified password accepted by Oracle, even before it gets into doing anything with data.

You are best off installing the [Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html) (Basic and ODBC supplement).