# Unable to execute macro from a laptop that does not have Oracle

Tags: oracle, vba, excel

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB from my excel Macro.  This Macro runs fine when I am running it on a laptop that has Oracle components installed. 
When I run it on a laptop that has no Oracle components installed it throws an error stating `Could not connect to the database. Check your username and password. Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are part of Oracle 7.3.3 or later client software installation`.

I am trying to connect to Oracle using the following parameters:-

```
Dim dbConnect As ADODB.Connection
Dim strUserName As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim strDatabase As String

Set dbConnect = New ADODB.Connection

dbConnect.Open ( _
"User ID=" & strUserName & "; Password=" & strPassword & "; Data Source=" & strDatabase & "; Provider=msdaora")
```

Majority of our users do not have Oracle installed.

Comment: Download Oracle Instant Client package from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html unpack it and place in a %PATH% variable.

Comment: isnt there a way to avoid downloading this package and bypass this error message?  Then this will be a hell of a task to install it on all users machine.

Comment: You can avoid installing the Oracle client and not get the error message by not trying to connect to an Oracle database.

Comment: Duplicate candidates:  [question-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342442/connect-excel-to-oracle), [question-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287477/not-able-to-connect-from-excel2003-to-oracle-server).

Comment: Thanks for the information ThinkJEt, but I dont think I will be able to download and install 80MB file on users machine. If I need to install, I am looking at a very basic installer. 

Can I install the "Instant Client Package - Basic Lite" or "Instant Client Package - ODBC" ? – Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access Oracle Database without corresponding components.

[ADO is just a programming interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to access various data providers, so it depends on lower level components.

`Provider=msdaora` parameter specifies ["Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and uses OLE DB layer to represent data access components as object-oriented API.

In turn, [OLE DB is just an object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which represents underlying data access level. In case of Oracle Database this level represented by Oracle Client components, so you need to install it if you want to connect to Oracle.

Also note, that MS OLE DB Provider for Oracle [have a number of limitations, outdated and not supported](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244661) and uses very very old OCI7 call interface.

To simplify deployment you can use [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Xcopy Deployment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html).  It weights less then 80MB and can be deployed without running of Universal Installer application. As noted in readme.txt file it can be installed just in 3 steps:

1. Download the ODAC (xcopy version) zip file to a directory for staging ODAC products.
2. Unzip ODAC (xcopy version) zip file to expand the contents.
3. Execute install.bat to install and configure ODAC products.

This component substitutes Microsoft OLE DB provider and already contains latest Oracle client implementation which can be accessed from Excel VBA applications (look for connect string formats [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/)).

Comment: Thanks for the information ThinkJEt, but I dont think I will be able to download and install 80MB file on users machine.  
If I need to install, I am looking at a very basic installer. 

Can I install "Instant Client Package - Basic Lite" or "Instant Client Package - ODBC" ?

Comment: @user2851053 Sorry, I didn't experiment with such type of installations but it seems to be possible to repack this installations for your own needs by removing С++ libraries and symbol files and adding OLE DB part from Xcopy installation variant. OLE DB installed just by importing settings into registry - examine configure.bat